# Javascript object not working in IE7

Tags: javascript

I have created the following javascript object dynamically (from PHP):

```
var t_feed = '';
t_feed += '[';
t_feed += '{name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121630545879900161", description: "This is the body of the tweat"},';
t_feed += '{name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121622456363524097", description: "This is the body of the tweat"},';
t_feed += '{name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121614678341320706", description: "This is the body of the tweat"}';
t_feed += ']';
twitterFeeds[0] = eval(t_feed);
```

This works fine in IE8+, but I get the following error in IE7:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'thumbnail': object is
>   null or undefined.

I get this when I try and access the thumbnail property like this:

```
$.each(twitterFeeds[id], function(i,item){
    alert(item.thumbnail);
});
```

Why does that fail in IE7 and is there a different way of defining a list or object that WILL work?

Comment: Why are you generating a string and then evaling it instead of just inserting the code directly? And why are you doing it by hand instead of using `json_encode`?

Comment: Why are you using eval? Why not just build the object?

Comment: Why are you assigning it to a string and then eval-ing it? It's just a JSON `t_feed = [{'name':"Tom Thumb", .... ]`

Comment: Did you try `twitterFeeds[0] = eval('(' + t_feed ')');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As a general rule, if you’re using eval() there’s probably something wrong with your design.](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval)

You may want to try parsing this string as [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) instead of using eval(), and then work from there.

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare the array first

```
var twitterFeeds = []; // declaration
twitterFeeds[0] = eval(t_feed);
alert(twitterFeeds);
```

Comment: He says, `"This works fine in IE8+, but I get the following error in IE7:"`.

Comment: @BheshGurung different behaviors, in ie6-7 an array instance is required

Comment: var twitterFeeds = []; is necessary in ie6-7.

Comment: @wes: Sorry. I thought he had just picked a part of his code and that declared somewhere (above). Anyway +1. Learned something.

Comment: BheshGurung Mufasa :) I fight with ie6-7-8 every **** day

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `eval` is unnecessary. Use the code directly:

```
var t_feed = [
 {name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121630545879900161", description: "This is the body of the tweat"},
 {name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121622456363524097", description: "This is the body of the tweat"},
 {name: "Tom Thumb", thumbnail: "images/Tom_Thumb.jpg", link: "http://twitter.com/cnnbrk/statuses/121614678341320706", description: "This is the body of the tweat"}
];
twitterFeeds[0] = t_feed;
```

UPDATE: As [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) pointed out, it would be even cleaner to use PHP (assuming a valid class is created) and initialize a new Array with the instances in the array, then use `json_encode` on it. That way you don't have to worry about the syntax and escaping characters safely.

UPDATE 2: If you don't initialize twitterFeeds first it will also fail. Have you done that? If not, change to `var twitterFeeds = [ t_feed ]`;